# Android: HTTP-Request fails often and is slow

Tags: android, http, url, timeout, wifi

I'm using following stupid code to download some data:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
request.setURI(new URI(url));
request.setHeader("User-Agent","Android Browser");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
in=response.getEntity().getContent();
len=(int)response.getEntity().getContentLength();
if (len<=0) return null;
data=new byte[len];
...
```

Downloading data this way is incredibly slow and often fails with a connection timeout. The same happens on other users devices so the configuration of my network should not be the reason.

On the other hand the given "url" works fine when I type it into a normal browser, it is fast and returns a result nearly immediately. My Android device and the "normal" computer with that browser are running on same WLAN network. So what could be wrong here?

Comment: What's after the `data=new byte[len]; ...` part? I can see this being slow due to poor performance in the receive buffer code.

Comment: There I read() the data from the input stream. Menwhile I identified two lines of code that cause a huge delay: client.execute(request) and that in.read() - both simply need a very long time until they come back. Btw: the download method is called out of an own thread - but that should not be a problem!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you do something funny outside of quoted code, could you please run this function and see in the log how long does it take to finish the request?

```
function check_fetch_time(String url) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    try {
        flushContent( response.getEntity().getContent() );
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    Log.v(TAG, "page fetched in " + elapsed + "ms");
}
```

---

> 20 seconds. Yes, really seconds, not milliseconds.

Well, something is definitely not right here. Could you please open the browser on your phone and try to access the web? If the browser access is equally slow, this it not a problem with your software, maybe your neighbours are microwaving their sausages and disrupting your wifi. However, if the browser opens pages almost instantly (within a second or two), then something is funny with your program. In that case I would create empty HelloWorld project, copy `check_fetch_time()` there and try again.

Comment: 20 seconds. Yes, really seconds, not milliseconds. I used heise.de, a page that is really fast. I have the feeling it is a bit faster when I'm running the App on the device directly and not within the debugger. The emulator is never used for my tests.

Comment: @Elmi, make sure you are using a WIFI network, not a 3G or even GPRS network when running on you real device.

Comment: As stated above both are running on the same WiFi network: the desktop system I used for speed comparison and the Android device that is that incredibly slow.

Comment: @lenik is possible to show progress bar based on the time it will take to upload?

Answer (score 0):

For me there is a huge difference between running an app in the emulator (slow) and running it in a phone (fast). The timeout is probably because of the webserver which closes the connection after a time. But also try using a buffered reader instead.

```
    private static JSONArray getJSON(String url) {
    // initialize
    InputStream is = null;
    JSONArray res = null;

    // http post
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }

    // convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        res = new JSONArray(sb.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    return res;
}
```